# What exactly are the differences between a National Park and a National Forest?

Tags: usa, terminology, national-parks

In the United States, most big national parks are surrounded by national forests.  I know that you can do "dispersed camping" in the National Forest, but not the National Park, but other than that, why is there a distinction between the two?

Comment: See also: [Is a National Forest always a Forest?](http://outdoors.stackexchange.com/q/3543/566) at The Great Outdoors SE (where I think this question would fit a little bit better).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There's a good description of the difference between the two on the [National Parks website](http://www.nps.gov/grsm/planyourvisit/np-versus-nf.htm)

The full version is at the link above, but in short :

> **National parks** emphasize strict preservation of pristine areas. They
>   focus on protecting natural and historic resources "unimpaired for
>   future generations." Park rangers work for the National Park Service
>   (NPS) under the Department of Interior.
>
> **National forests**, on the other hand, emphasize not only resource
>   preservation, but other kinds of use as well. Under this concept of
>   "multiple use," national forests are managed to provide Americans with
>   a wide variety of services and commodities, including lumber, cattle
>   grazing, mineral products and recreation with and without vehicles.
>   The national forests are managed by forest rangers with the US Forest
>   Service (USFS) under the Department of Agriculture.

Answer (score 2):

National Forests are federally owned and protected land, but, unlike parks, they are not *neccesarily* designated and managed for *public use* in the same manner as a National Park. In many cases, National Forest land is in fact even leased for commercial purposes, including, for example, many vacation spots and ski resorts.